# Java8 doesn't work with Play framework 2.3

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, playframework, java-8

I'm having a problem to run my play project using java8.

I've already changed the eclipse property, windows Environment Variables ,used play clean and checked the Java_home.

This is the error that i get when I try to run:

[image: https://s5.postimg.org/pvu1zhnp3/play_error.png]

Here's [a link](http://postimg.org/image/4yxtutpo3/) to the print of the error.

Comment: What is version of `Play` you use?

Comment: I've changed to 2.3 but it's not working yet.